# Got stung by this flying bug in Death Valley and Arches, what is it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: bug]

We camped in Death Valley and these guys were attracted to light and ended up stinging us. Didn't hurt as bad as a bee Sting. Any ideas what they are? Couldn't find them doing a Google search or image search.

Comment: Please provide an approximate size. Also, the more information/photos you provide, the better chance of getting the correct answer. Please [edit] your post with more detail. Thanks

Comment: A photo with the wing venation in focus should be among your additions; from what is here, we can say Hymenoptera (bees, wasps, ants, et cetera), but not an ant (the antennae don't have a distinct angle between the first segment and the second).